# Adwaita on Xfce

Tags: themes, xfce, gtk

I like the default theme of Ubuntu but want to keep Xubuntu because it is lightweight. Is it possible to install Adwaita theme on Xfce?

Comment: Is it not listed under Settings -> Appearance?  One thing to remember is that Themes that can be used on other Desktop Environments may not look the same on others due to different elements that are used for each environment.  There are lots of themes for Xfce4 available at https://www.xfce-look.org/browse/ but I do recommend that you install `ocs-url` via `sudo apt install ocs-url`

Comment: @Terrance For me it is indeed listed under Settings->Appearance. But it does not apply to all windows. For some windows (apparently those that do not use CSD), another theme is applied to draw the title bar and window border. This can be configured under Settings->Window Manager, but there is not "Adwaita" theme to choose...

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's default theme is `Yaru`. `Adwaita` is the default theme for GNOME 3, available by default in my case in XUbuntu 22.04.

For `yaru` theme, simply open terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) and run the command below to install it:

```
sudo apt install yaru-theme-gtk
```

If you meant for the new `LibAdwaita`, that is default in most recent GNOME 42/43 core apps, you may try the [Adw-GTK3](https://github.com/lassekongo83/adw-gtk3) theme. Just download the tarball in [its release](https://github.com/lassekongo83/adw-gtk3/releases) page, extract and move the 2 theme folders (`adw-gtk3` & `adw-gtk3-dark`) into '`.themes`' folder in user home. (*open Home folder, press Ctrl+H, and create `.themes` folder if not exist*)

Finally, search for and open "`Appearance`" from start menu and choose your favorite theme.